# How to know if a question is flagged apart from guessing from the downvotes?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Apart from the visible down-votes to a particular question considered as off-topic or irrelevant, how to know that it is **flagged** for deletion with `x` number of flags. Same thing for **answers** too.

I have the idea that it is only shown to Mods for deletion, since they are going to delete it or reconsider it.

**P.S**: If the only function of flagging is to ping mods for attention for action on it, then I guess, even this question needs to be deleted. Please comment so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already view close votes on your own questions at 250 reputation, https://askubuntu.com/privileges/view-close-votes

For casting close votes at 3,000 reputation, https://askubuntu.com/privileges/close-questions

Or you can wait for 10,000 reputation for mod tools. https://askubuntu.com/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: The first Links shows the Votes that can be cast in a day by that User.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though , View the image at the [close vote privilege](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/close-questions) , apart from that i did a research before posting question on it, though not a fully-fledged one :)

Comment: the first link talks about viewing the close votes that are cast, notice the number is next to the "exact duplicate". But in reference  to your question, the "mod tools" is the only way to see the "flags".

Comment: Really sorry for wrong justification , it says `Click on the "close" link under any of **your** questions, under the question text and to the left side.`

Comment: So you need to wait for more reputation. On the right side of the privileges pages you can see how close you are to a certain feature

Comment: Yep that seems like it.Thanks for all these links. Just noticed its right side.

Answer (score 2):

Flag for deletion is a workaround to let low rep users close things. High rep users can see it in tools however.

Its probably by design that you can't view if its flagged.